# Training of a CNN stops at the seventh epoch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, transfer-learning

I am doing image classification, and I am using transfer learning to do this. My problem is that if I build the network, and then I train it, the training process stops at the seventh epoch, even if I set the number of epochs to be equal to 100.

Is there a reason why this could happen? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] I have images of 4 different weather conditions, and they are in .jpg format. My code is the following:

```
trainingset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train'
testset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Test_HWI'



batch_size = 31
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255,\
    zoom_range=0.1,\
    rotation_range=10,\
    width_shift_range=0.1,\
    height_shift_range=0.1,\
    horizontal_flip=True,\
    vertical_flip=False)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   directory=trainingset,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=testset,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False
)

num_samples = train_generator.n
num_classes = train_generator.num_classes
input_shape = train_generator.image_shape

classnames = [k for k,v in train_generator.class_indices.items()]

print("Image input %s" %str(input_shape))
print("Classes: %r" %classnames)

print('Loaded %d training samples from %d classes.' %(num_samples,num_classes))
print('Loaded %d test samples from %d classes.' % 
(test_generator.n,test_generator.num_classes))
```

now, I use as pre-trained network a VGG16, and the code is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten,\
                     Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D, 
GlobalAveragePooling2D,\
                     UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras import regularizers
from keras import optimizers


from keras import applications
from keras.models import Model, Input


def load_backbone_net(input_shape):

# define input tensor
input0 = Input(shape=input_shape)

# load a pretrained model on imagenet without the final dense layer
feature_extractor = applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input0)


feature_extractor = feature_extractor.output
feature_extractor = Model(input=input0, output=feature_extractor)
optimizer = 'adam' #alternative 'SGD'

feature_extractor.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

return feature_extractor


def transferNet(feature_extractor, num_classes, output_layer_name, trainable_layers):

# get the original input layer tensor
input_t = feature_extractor.get_layer(index=0).input

# set the feture extractor layers as non-trainable
for idx,layer in enumerate(feature_extractor.layers):
  if layer.name in trainable_layers:
    layer.trainable = True
  else:
    layer.trainable = False

# get the output tensor from a layer of the feature extractor
output_extractor = feature_extractor.get_layer(name = output_layer_name).output

#output_extractor = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4))(output_extractor)

# flat the output of a Conv layer
flatten = Flatten()(output_extractor) 
flatten_norm = BatchNormalization()(flatten)

# add a Dense layer
dense = Dropout(0.4)(flatten_norm)
dense = Dense(200, activation='relu')(dense)
dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)

# add a Dense layer
dense = Dropout(0.4)(dense)
dense = Dense(100, activation='relu')(dense)
dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)

# add the final output layer
dense = BatchNormalization()(dense)
dense = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dense)


model = Model(input=input_t, output=dense, name="transferNet")

optimizer = 'adam' #alternative 'SGD'
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

return model

# load the pre-trained model
feature_extractor = load_backbone_net(input_shape)
feature_extractor.summary()


# choose the layer from which you can get the features (block5_pool the end, 
glob_pooling to get the pooled version of the output)
name_output_extractor = "block5_pool"
trainable_layers = ["block5_conv3"]

# build the transfer model
transfer_model = transferNet(feature_extractor, num_classes, 
name_output_extractor, trainable_layers)
transfer_model.summary()
```

and then I train the network:

```
from keras import callbacks
# fit the transferNet on the training data
stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3)

steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
val_steps = test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size+1

try:
    history_transfer = transfer_model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
epochs=100, verbose=1, callbacks=[stopping],\
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,\
                    validation_data=test_generator,\
                    validation_steps=val_steps)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your data, problem and architecture you're using? Could you please update us with code and tensorboard charts?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have edited my question.

Comment: Exactly how large is your data set? What's class balance?

Comment: I have 3200 images in my training set, and 800 in my test set. The dataset is balanced, so in the training set I have 800 images per class.

Comment: Does architecture look ok in tensorboard?

Comment: Have you tried different learning rates? `Early stopping` `patience` parameters is set just to 3 epochs. I'd suggest using a bit higher values.

Comment: By increasing patience from 3 to 50 it seems to go further with the training. I hope it goes ahead until the epoch 100. So what gives problem seems to be the earlystopping. Thanks!